# Как получить текущую папку

Tags: ruby

Такая проблема. 
Я написал простой руби скрипт, сделал его исполняемым, и сделал на него ссылку в другой папке.
Как мне узнать из руби, в какой папке лежит оригинал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Винда не под рукой, но теоретически так:

[`__dir__()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__)

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло. Правда не винда, mac os.

Comment: Тогда привычней использовать термин "директория" вместо "папка".

Answer (score 0):

Универсальное решение Ruby 2.2.0+

```
puts Dir.pwd
```